# deleting from UITableView crashes app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a UITableView and I implemented the delete from table swipe method.
For some reason, the assignment of arrays is causing the app to crash.
I would like to know why.

two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *mruItems;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *mruSearchItems;
 . 
 .
 .
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle != UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        return;

    NSString *searchString = [self.mruSearchItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.mruItems removeObject:searchString];

    [self.mruSearchItems release];

    // This line crashes:
    self.mruSearchItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems];

    [self.searchTableView reloadData];
   }
```

It is as if after mruItems's objects has been removed, it can't help initialize mruSearchItems...

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

`@synthesize mruItems,mruSearchItems;`  <--Debugger points here

Comment: What is the exact crash?  It's probably logged some more information to the Console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is double releasing causes crash.

```
[self.mruSearchItems release];
```

This makes refcount -1

```
self.mruSearchItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems];
```

This makes refcount -1

Since mruSearchItems has "retain" in property attributes, your assign to it will cause another refcount -1.

So either remove the release line or set it to nil after release it and before assign to it.

---

Edit:
This line

```
self.mruSearchItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems];
```

causes memory leak, fix it like this:

```
self.mruSearchItems = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems] autorelease];
```

or:

```
NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems];
self.mruSearchItems = tmpArray;
[tmpArray release];
```

---

Edit Again

What does "retain" in property actually do?

Take mruSearchItems as example, when you assign it:

```
- (void)setMruSearchItems:(NSArray *)newArray
{
    [newArray retain];
    [mruSearchItems release]; // this lines causes a second release to the old value
    mruSearchItems = newArray;
}
```

Comment: The retain is supposed to up the refcount not decrease it

Comment: The retain causes increase refcount of the new alloc-ed NSArray, it will also decrease the refcount of the old object which mruSreachItems points to.

Comment: I am sorry. But I think I don't follow... The "=" calls the setter, which is retain. Decreasing of refcounts only happens upon release/autorelease Afaik... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, you did miss something. Please refer to my answer, I edited it again to explain the things happen in background.

Comment: Just imagine: every time you assign something to a property with "retain" attribute, it will retain the new object, if it never releases the old object, there will be a lot of memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to release the object and reallocate it? if you make `mruSearchItems` an `NSMutableArray` then you can simply call:

```
[mruSearchItems removeAllObjects];
[mruSearchItems addObjectsFromArray:self.mruItems];
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting problem at releasing array.i hope this will help you

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
NSString *searchString = [self.mruSearchItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.mruSearchItems removeObjectAtIndex:searchString]
[self.searchTableView reloadData];
```

}